# Backbone: Json load via Ajax vs. Bootstrapped

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have a project where I need to load one json via Ajax (async of the page load) and one json that could "bootstapped" on page load.

Is the code below considered async of page load? On success of the model fetch I load the page with the item json or is this considered "bootstrapped" on page load? what does the other one look like then?

```
this.model.fetch({
            success: function(res) {
                var template = _.template( $('#mainForm').html(), { item : res.attributes});
                that.el.html(template);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519515/backbonejs-collection-reset-vs-collection-fetch

Comment: Bootstrapping usually refers to data that is inlined right in the page, something like `m = new Model({ a1: 'v1', a2: 'v2', ... })`

Comment: what if i need to bootstrap a json file? is there a way I can get the object inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was meant by Bootstrapping was through including the JSON through a PHP file then translating it to a Javascript object that could be loaded on page load before the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

The two things are completely independent.

AJAX is a technology to retrieve data from the server without refreshing the page. It is done "in the background" and is completely separate from page rendering.

Bootstrapping is a general term to bypass something that usually requires more resources. I suppose you are bypassing creating a template and a Backbone View here, which were actually a recommended way of doing things.

Now if I understand right, you are "bootstrapping" only one part of the data, whereas use the proper Backbone approach (hopefully) for the other. But then you already have resources (code structure) to do it right, then why skipping it for the other?

It may look short here but can easily expand and create a mess in your code.